# Fail to evaluate Angular expression in a template when using ES6 syntax for directive and controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

*Angular 1.6.4*

I want to learn how to use ES6 syntax in Angular 1.x directives and controllers. [This is a git repo](https://github.com/SergeyBondarenko/helloworld-angularjs-webpack) for my hello world app I write to understand the ways to do it.

I can't understand why the following expression is not evaluated.

**pages/about/about.html**

```
<p>Its Angular 1.6 {{ vm.name }} app.</p>
```

I see only "*Its Angular 1.6  app.*" on the web page. There is no error in Chrome Dev console.

What am I doing wrong here?

**app.js**

```
import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import ngAnimate from 'angular-animate';

import {home} from './pages/home/home';
import {about} from './pages/about/about';

const myApp = angular.module('app', [
  uiRouter,
  ngAnimate,
  home.name,
  about.name
]);

require('./directives')(myApp);
```

**pages/about/about.js**

```
import {aboutDirective} from './about.directive';
import angular from 'angular';

export const about = angular.module('about', [])
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('about', {
    url: '/about',
    template: '<about></about>'
  });
})
.directive('about', aboutDirective);
```

**pages/about/about.html**

```
<section>
  <div>
    <p>Its Angular 1.6 {{ vm.name }} app.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

**pages/about/about.directive.js**

```
import template from './about.html';
import {AboutController as controller} from './about.controller';

export const aboutDirective = function () {
  return {
    template,
    controller,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    scope: {},
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true
  };
};
```

**pages/about/about.controller.js**

```
class AboutController {
  constructor () {
    this.name == 'hello world';
  }
}

export {AboutController};
```

Comment: this.name = 'hello world'; '==' is comparison

Comment: this is why people need typescript. at least to avoid this kind of silly mistakes:)

Comment: OMG! Yes, it is the problem. Thank you, guys.